# Nesting IF statements in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

How do I nest IF statements in Excel 2010? I found my inspiration trying to organize data from [Evolus Pencil Support Tickets](http://code.google.com/p/evoluspencil/issues/list?can=1&q=&sort=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary%20Attachments%20Stars%20Opened%20Closed%20Modified%20BlockedOn%20Blocking%20Blocked%20MergedInto%20Reporter%20Cc).

Here is my desired result: I want to nest IF statments to choose between different status levels, such as Fixed, New, Invalid, Done, Duplicate, etc. However, I had to make several tables to achieve this and when I tried to test it, the IF statement only gives me the first choice (Fixed).

Here is the formula to test whether the number is 1-6 and add on the number, and the status level:

```
=IF(U2="1",
CONCATENATE(VALUE(U2),$V$2,IF(U2="2",
CONCATENATE(VALUE(U2),$W$2,IF(U2="3",
CONCATENATE(VALUE(U2),$X$2,IF(U2="4",
CONCATENATE(VALUE(U2),$Y$2,IF(U2="5",
CONCATENATE(VALUE(U2),$Z$2,IF(U2="6",
CONCATENATE(VALUE(U2),$AA$2,"NO")
```

The result, however, in the corresponding cells is: Cell is U2 1FixedFALSE Cell is U3 false

Please check out the spreadsheet here

http://win7guruquestions.posterous.com/my-spreadsheet-illustrating-selection-and-if

I hope that you can help me with this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the formula posted is missing closing brackets.  On the assumption it should be

```
=IF(U2="1",CONCATENATE(VALUE(U2),$V$2),
IF(U2="2",CONCATENATE(VALUE(U2),$W$2),
IF(U2="3",CONCATENATE(VALUE(U2),$X$2),
IF(U2="4",CONCATENATE(VALUE(U2),$Y$2),
IF(U2="5",CONCATENATE(VALUE(U2),$Z$2),
IF(U2="6",CONCATENATE(VALUE(U2),$AA$2),"NO"))))))
```

it works, provided values in U2 are entered as strings.

An alternative formula:

```
=IF(AND(VALUE(U2)>=1,VALUE(U2)<=6),U2&INDEX($V$2:$Z$2,1,VALUE(U2)),"NO")
```

Comment: Thank you, I will check it out and report my findings.  I appreciate your response.

Comment: The first formula works, thank you so much.  This will help me to prioritize certain categories.  I am curious why there is an N in the alternative formula you have provided.

Comment: @Jon About N(). In checking my facts before answering your comment, I realised I made a mistake.  N() returns a value converted to a number, but any text returns 0.  I need to use VALUE instead in this formula.  I've edited the answer to reflect this

Comment: @Jon if you find the answer solves your question, you should accept it (click the tick).

Comment: Wonderful explanations, you are extremely helpful.  I did notice that it always resulted in NO as the output.  I will try using your revised formula.